# Is there a way to define a var in PhpStorm Template in order to get a combobox for the user?

Tags: phpstorm, apache-velocity

In PhpStorm, I would like in a custom PHP template to define a variable in order to display a combobox. It's quite easy to get an input for the user inside a template...

**My Template**

[image]

**Result**

[image]

But I would like for another variable, let a list of choice for the user with a combobox like the PHP Class template.

I tried this without success :

```
${choices} = ["choice 1", "choice 2"]
```

Is it possible in PhpStorm ?

Comment: Not a 100% but from what I can see so far: not possible. https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-198458

Comment: Another ticket (already got it starred but could not find yesterday somehow, hmm...): https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-182705